# GridView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-nestedscrollview

I'am trying to build an android application, I have a GridView inside a NestedScrollView,my problem was that the gridview is not showing all the elements,i resolved that problem with adding scroll to the grivView.but now i have another problem which is that when i scroll sometimes the nestedScrollView move and sometimes the gridView.[image]

Comment: What is the exact problem you're trying to fix?

Comment: When i scroll the gridView to see the points at the bottom the nestedscrollview is scrolling too,how can i fix that or disable the scrolling while i'am scrolling the gridview.

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView scrollview = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollId);` to retrieve the nestedScrollView then disable it by calling `scrollview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled)`

Answer (score 3):

This solution work me.

```
    public void setGridViewHeightBasedOnChildren(GridView gridView, int columns) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = gridView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int items = listAdapter.getCount();
        int rows = 0;

        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(0, null, gridView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        float x = 1;
        if( items > columns ){
            x = items/columns;
            rows = (int) (x + 1);
            totalHeight *= rows;
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight;
        gridView.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

After you have called `setAdapter` on your gridview, just call

`setGridViewHeightBasedOnChildren(your girdview object, no of grid view columns)`

Comment: rows = (int) (x + 1); is getting 1 extra empty row below. Instead rows = (int) x; is working fine for me